Are there any commentaries regarding the first disciples of Christ already being disciples of John?
In studying through the gospels chronologically, I realized that at least two of the apostles, Andrew and most likely John, were already close disciples of John the Baptist before they met Christ. Andrew went to get his brother Peter, which implies he wasn't far away. It occurred to me that, at least for the inner core, these first disciples of Jesus did not start following Him out of a vacuum. They were spiritual men and were most probably seeking for the Messiah, as directed by John. It seems worthy of note.
I could not find  any biblical commentary on this , to get more information. For example, where was John baptizing? These were working men; yet they were hanging around John, away from home. Bathabera is traditionally considered to be near the north end of the Dead Sea and east of Jerusalem, and about 70 miles from Gallilee. This makes sense considering  John the Baptist preached in the wilderness, and Christ was immediately led out there after His baptism. I would like to know, besides if there is any commentary on the first disciples before they met Christ, what is considered a reliable current source for ancient geography.
Thank you.

Up-voted +1. I agree with your conclusions. Peter, Andrew, John and probably James took time off their family fishing businesses to respond to the ministry of John the Baptist, at which time they met with Jesus and followed him, leaving John. Returning to Galilee, they continued with their businesses whereupon Jesus found them and, this time, called them to the ministry to be fishers of men, whereupon they left their family businesses. This is very clear from the gospel accounts.

Welcome to SE-C. Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. Please also see the archive of 15,000 question/answer contributions as to how these policies play out in practice. Moderators are elected by the community of users to maintain the integrity of the site.

This commentary on Mark's gospel account is helpful. It details the geographic scope of John's ministry like this, regarding ch. 1 vss 4 & 5:

"The desert region - The arid region west of the Dead Sea, whose
inhabitants included those who wrote and preserved the Dead Sea
Scrolls... "The whole Judean countryside and all the people of
Jerusalem went out to him" - all - Obvious hyperbole, indicating
the high interest created by John's preaching. For centuries Israel
had had no prophet. Jordan River - The principal river, beginning in
the snows of Mount Hermon and ending in the Dead Sea. Its closest
point to Jerusalem is about 20 miles." NIV Study Bible, p.1463, 1987
edition

Notice the clues about the people who paid attention to John's preaching. They were already hoping to see Messiah in their life-time, and many wondered if John could be that one. Luke's gospel account shows that John was doing what the prophecy foretold; preparing the way for Messiah. He clearly stated that he was not the Messiah, who would come after him. See Luke 3:15-18. The great crowds of people paying attention to his preaching, and who were baptised by him would include some who Jesus later called to be his disciples.
That is because those who would receive Jesus as the Messiah had to be prepared first, by John's preparatory ministry (Matthew 3:1-3 cf. Isaiah 40:3 & Malachi 3:1). The beginning of the gospel came with John the Baptist. Then, after Herod put him in prison, Jesus began his ministry, and already had a selection of earnest disciples of John's to choose from. All who were baptized of John had first repented of their sin. Those so prepared, recognise the call of the Master and respond swiftly, forsaking all.
It could well be that all of the 12 apostles had first been prepared by John the Baptist's preaching. John's preaching is mentioned twice. The first preaching was in the wilderness. Then there was baptism in Jordan, with confession of sins. Note this comment:

"Forgiveness of sins is not mentioned. Confession of sins is entailed
in receiving John's words and being baptised as a result. This baptism
was unto remission of sins. It, itself, is not the actual remission of
sins. Under John's ministry, sins are exposed; sins are admitted; sins
are confessed. No more... The baptism of John was administered only to
those who went out of Israel, Israelites, and attended his baptism in
Jordan... His preaching exposed conditions and his preaching heralded
the One who could answer those conditions." The Beginning of the
Gospel, pp39-40, Nigel Johnstone, 2012,
http://www.belmontpublications.co.uk

John was the link from the old to the new. He had to preach repentance to prepare people to receive the Messiah, the Messenger of the Covenant. People had to confess their sins and be baptised in recognition that their sins were exposed. He came to turn people from darkness to the Light of the World, Jesus Christ (John 1:7). Those who turned to the Light John pointed to could then receive this Light and have the power to become the sons of God by being born again (John 1:12-13).

"Being born again necessitates a preparation by God Almighty himself,
by the words of the preparative messenger which he, himself,
authorises and sends. Receiving these words, there will be a cleansing
that will separate a soul and remove from that soul that which
prohibits the growth of the word within it. This, and this only, is
the beginning of the gospel." (Ibid. p 75)


Repentance is to have the mind itself changed, not merely its contents. Repentance is to
have a different mind, with a different way of working. The beginning
of the gospel is the changed mind which results from the ministry of a
preparative messenger... When God gives a man a new mind, in which he
writes his laws; and a new heart, in which he also writes his laws;
then, in such a condition, after such a baptism, is a man ready to
receive the messenger of the covenant... The ministry of John the
Baptist, the preparative messenger, is a ministry that prepares the
heart and mind for the coming of Christ to the soul, as conveyed in
the gospel. It, itself, does not convey Christ. It prepares for that
event. And if the preparation is not received, nor will Christ be
received." (Ibid. pp 45-46)

The simple fact that all those who Jesus called to be his disciples came readily, indicates that they had first been disciples of John the Baptist - prepared with the preaching of the beginning of the gospel by John.
